# Including page layout to Laravel project

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-blade

I was supplied with a custom layout for the login page of my Laravel project.

When I opened login.html file, which represents the layout for that specific page I saw such links

```
<!-- Base Css Files -->
        <link href="assets/libs/jqueryui/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="assets/libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="assets/libs/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
...
```

So I figured that I only need to copy the assets folder, which came with the template (there are all needed bootstraps, jqueries and whatnot) to my projects app\resources\assets directory

Now, when I copied the code from login.html into my login.blade.php view and copied the templates' assets folder to app\resources\assets it doesnt work. It only displays naked html code when I open the page.

What am I doing wrong in linking the assets folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access assets, you have two ways to approach it. Either using Elixir/gulp or to use direct access.

Gulp is a node.js application that reads your assets files, whether JS, CSS, Coffee, etc...and combine them in single files. Gulp reads the files defined in the `gulpfile.js`, and you can access the output files in your blade file using `elixir()`.
You can read more about Elixir [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/elixir).

In your specific case, you can just place the files under the `public/` directory. So Laravel treats `public` as the root directory, and if you want to read the file `assets/css/foo.css` just place the file in `public/assets/css/foo.css`

Comment: But the template I have is written in plain php, not blade. Do I have to change all the links from that form:

'<link href="assets/libs/jqueryui/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />'

to:

'<link href="{{ URL: asset('assets/libs/jqueryui/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet') }}" />'

Comment: blade is just php files, but the blade engine makes your life easier. For example instead of <?php echo $myvar ?> you can just use {{$myvar}}.

Comment: So, you do not need to change anything, just place the assets in the correct directories relative to public/ directory.

Comment: When I put the assets folder to public directory and saved the view in views\admin\login.php it's still displaying naked html.
The extention of the view should be .php, not .blade.php, right? (neither is working correctly anyways)

Comment: it should be login.blade.php, and when you call it from controller you should call it like that: return view('admin.login');

Comment: That's my route:   Route::get('/admin/login', 'AdminAccessController@login'); and the controller:   public function login()
    {
      return view('admin.login');
    }

Everything looks fine to me, but still isn't working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95839/discussion-between-mina-youssef-and-manjii).

Answer (score 1):

The resources folder is (like the name says) for the resources. 
If you don't want/need to build/compile/min your scripts, then just put them in the public folder, so you can access them from your template.

In your case
`public/assets/libs...`